# Blue line in the drop down menu in mobile version

Tags: html, css, r, quarto

I'm using R and trying to publish a website using quarto, and it works perfectly fine after publishing and when I see it through desktop (both desktop and mobile version). But when I see the website with my iphone, and click the drop down menus, I see this blue lines.

[image]

This is what I have at the very bottom of the .yml file

```
format:
  html:
    css: styles.css
    toc: true
```

And I also have tried the inserting following codes in my css file but didn't work either.

```
.header-menu-sidebar .nav-ul a {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

```
.et_mobile_menu {
  border-top: 2px solid
  ##ff5733!important;
}
```

Any ideas or tips are welcome! Thanks!

Update

1. This is my .yml file

   ```css
   project:
     type: website

   website:
     title: "helloworld"
     navbar:
       left:
         - text: Home
           menu:
             - href: index.qmd
           
       right:
         - text: ABOUT
           menu: 
             - text: Education

   format:
     html:
       css: styles.css
       toc: true
   ```
2. This is what I have in my styles.css

```
/* css styles */


.navbar-dark {
    background-color: #222222;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way you can provide a basic rmarkdown document that supports this issue?

Comment: @r2evans Hi! I just updated the post!

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking you might be able to make this question end-to-end reproducible, starting with a "hello world" rmarkdown ... while that by itself isn't hard, I don't know what js-libraries you might be referencing, how you're creating the pull-down, etc.

Comment: @r2evans I was able to solve it! but thank you for trying to help me out!

Answer (score 1):

I found out that this only happen in safari. And I was able to solve it by inserting

```
outline: none;
```